# Wordpress add menu to page content using editor

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I can manage custom menus in Appearance -> Menus

Then, I can add any of these custom menus to the page content by inserting a shortcode like this in the editor:

```
[menu name="Menu1"]
```

**Question:**

How can I add a dropdown list to editor ( like *Formats* or even inside *Formats* ), that will list all custom menus available. A click on a custom menu shall insert it's shortcode to the page content.

Comment: IMO, this should go to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
//add this in your functions.php
function custom_menu( $atts ){
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => $atts['name'],
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

}
add_shortcode( 'menu', 'custom_menu' );
?>
```

then use shortcode like this
[menu name="menu_name"]

Comment: I can add shortcodes by hand, knowing the menu name. The question is if I can add an option to visual editor, so that I could select the menus from a list. A click on the selected menu should insert the corresponding shortcode automatically.

Comment: For this you have to create Shortcode TinyMCE Editor Button

Comment: See this link http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/